# The expression is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access:

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("MIDKalorimetar/Delete/{Id}/{Id2}/{Id3}/{Id4}/{Id5}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(DeleteKalorimetarVM modelVM)
{
        var model = await _db.ParametriMjerila.Where(x => x.Id == modelVM.Id).Include(d => d.Id == modelVM.Id2).Include(x=>x.Id == modelVM.Id3).Include(x => x.Id == modelVM.Id4).Include(x => x.Id == modelVM.Id5).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            
        return PartialView("Delete", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(ParametarMjerila parametrniMjerila)
{
    var model = await _db.ParametriMjerila.Where(x => x.Id == parametrniMjerila.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
     _db.ParametriMjerila.Remove(model);
     _db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
}
```

Button in Index for modal:

```
<button class="bg-transparent border-0" style=" background: transparent; border: 0; border: 0 !important; " data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-url="@Url.Action($"Delete/{@Model.Qi.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.Id}/{@Model.Qp.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.Id}/{@Model.Qs.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.Id}/{@Model.R.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.Id}/{@Model.SP.ElementAtOrDefault(x)?.Id}")">
```

Delete modal:

```
 @model VerifikacijaMjerila.ViewModels.MIDKalorimetar.DeleteKalorimetarVM

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Obriši</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="/MIDKalorimetar/Delete" method="post" id="forma">
            
             
           
            <input asp-for="Id" hidden/>
            <div class="d-flex mb-2">
            <div class="d-table "><label class="d-table-cell align-middle" style="font-weight:bold">Vrijednost karakteristike :</label></div>
            <p>@Model.VrijednostKarakteristike</p>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Id2" hidden/>
            <div class="d-flex mb-2">
            <div class="d-table "><label class="d-table-cell align-middle" style="font-weight:bold">Vrijednost karakteristike :</label></div>
            <p>@Model.VrijednostKarakteristike</p>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Id3" hidden/>
            <div class="d-flex mb-2">
            <div class="d-table "><label class="d-table-cell align-middle" style="font-weight:bold">Vrijednost karakteristike :</label></div>
            <p>@Model.VrijednostKarakteristike</p>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Id4" hidden/>
            <div class="d-flex mb-2">
            <div class="d-table "><label class="d-table-cell align-middle" style="font-weight:bold">Vrijednost karakteristike :</label></div>
            <p>@Model.VrijednostKarakteristike</p>
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Id5" hidden/>
            <div class="d-flex mb-2">
            <div class="d-table "><label class="d-table-cell align-middle" style="font-weight:bold">Vrijednost karakteristike :</label></div>
            <p>@Model.VrijednostKarakteristike</p>
            </div>
   
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary red" form="forma" data-save="modal">Obriši</button>
                <a href="/MIDKalorimetar/Index1" class="btn btn-warning">Nazad</a>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So am trying to display this IDs to modal, when I debbug I can see that IDs are passed to controller but it wont open delete modal and the following error appears:

> InvalidOperationException: The expression '(d.Id == __modelVM_Id2_1)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

Answer (score 0):

`Include` does not work like that. It is used to load [related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) which is represented with navigation properties.

If you want to access entities represented by one of the passed ids you can aggregate those ids into collection and use `Contains`:

```cs
var ids = new [] { modelVM.Id, modelVM.Id2, ...};
var model = await _db.ParametriMjerila
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Though `FirstOrDefaultAsync` does not make much sense to me in this case.

Comment: Thanks! this removed error but it only pass one Id to model. When I debbug It pass all Ids in ids array but in model I get only one id :/

Comment: @loranni TBH I completely do not understand what you are actually trying to do. Your code does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Its kinda complicated and not good from aspect of programming, but I need to do it this way, So I have html table with 5 columns, One row in table has 5 IDs, basically each cell has his own ID, becuse the data I display are in same table in database and they arent in any kind of relationship only difference is in column OznakaKarakteristike, What I want is when I click on delete row table to display 5 IDs, 5 cells that are in row  so I can choose what I want to delete

Comment: @loranni sounds like something what should be done purely on frontend until the `HttpDelete` invocation. Not sure why do you need to fetch something from db.

Answer (score 0):

Hello while using Include `CurrentClass.Include(x => x.YourClass)` use the whole class in the expression. And add property to the current class like this:

```
public YourClass YourClass{ get: set; }
```

If you have YourClassId as a ForeignKey to YourClass
You will have access to YourClass true CurrentClass.YourClass

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue a time a go i solved with this

[ForeignKey("ClassId")] public MySourceCustomClass myCustomClass { get; set; }

for ex

[ForeignKey("CityId")] public Cityes MyCity {get; set;}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).